# lua:How to use value from table 'A', in table 'B', which nested in table 'A'

Tags: scripting, lua, lua-table, nested-table

In real project, `TEST_TABLE` would contain much of `TEST_TABLE_NESTED`, each with its own `testVariable` and bunch of `testScript`. `test` function from `testScript` would be used in C++ code, and `TEST_TABLE_NESTED` tables would be added automatically from C++ code too.

```
TEST_TABLE =
{
    TEST_TABLE_NESTED =
    {
        testVariable = 5, 

        testScript =
        {
            test = function()

                print(testVariable, "hello") --How to access 'testVariable'?

            end
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
This is the actual scenario of using this script:

```
GameObjectScriptTables =
{
    GameObject_1 = --Container of scripts corresponding to some gameObject
    {
        gameObjectOwner = actual_object_passed_from_c++, --This is an actual object passed from c++

        GameObjectScript_1 = --This is a script with update(dt) method which will be called somwhere in c++ code
        {
            update = function(dt)

                --here I want to use some data from gameObjectOwner like position or velocity

            end
        }
    }

    GameObject_2 =
    {
        gameObjectOwner = actual_object_passed_from_c++,

        GameObjectScript_1 =
        {
            update = function(dt)

                --here I want to use some data from gameObjectOwner like position or velocity

            end
        },

        GameObjectScript_2 =
        {
            update = function(dt)

                --here I want to use some data from gameObjectOwner like position or velocity

            end
        }
    }

    --And so on
}
```

Idea is that exists some `testVariable` object (passed from C++), which data is used all over `TEST_TABLE_NESTED`. For me, above example looks natural for this task, but it prints `nil` instead of `5`. So how to acces a `testVariable` from `testScript` without printing a full path like `TEST_TABLE.TEST_TABLE_NESTED.testVariable`?

Comment: You can't. `testVariable` is not a closure for test function, but an index in TEST_TABLE_NESTED, which in turn is an index in TEST_TABLE. In order to access testVariable, you'd need access to TEST_TABLE_NESTED or TEST_TABLE. What's the actual scenario?

Comment: @W.B. I'm using it for game scripting. I added more information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made it work by providing a `gameObjectOwner` instance for each `GameObjectScript_N`. However I don't know is it expensive solution or not.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for something like a "parent" pointer, which tells table B about table A, but that doesn't exist. Internally, the only association they have is that one of A's values happens to be B, but any number of tables could contain B as a value. Which is B's parent?

If you want B to know about A, you'll need to tell it. You can add an extra parameter to `update` which receives the game owner object, or `update` can be a closure which contains the game owner as a bound variable, so on and so forth.